# Round float value with 6 not 5

Tags: javascript

I need some help on this, I have a big float value (Ex.: 18.235555).

**In some countries, rounding up begins from 6, and not from 5.**

I know use only 2 decimal, but I need something different:

*18.235555 = 18.24*

but this

*18.23666 = 18.24*

```
$('#val').html( Number(Math.round(1.005+'e2')+'e-2' ) );
```

Example: now I have this [https://jsfiddle.net/tevez15/ywm8bonp/][1]

```
var n = 1.665;
(Math.round( n * 100 )/100 ).toString()
```

Solution:  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/tevez15/ywm8bonp/

Comment: Show the code you are using to round the numbers. by the way, they are both mathematically correct.

Comment: I can't understand what the problem is. _18.235555 = 18.24_ is correct, so is _18.23666 = 18.24_

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but [this MDN section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) discusses rounding and provides source code for variations of decimal rounding which are not included in the standard.

Comment: I agree with @Regent, your intent is not clear. However, assuming you want to get `18.23` as the result, you need to use `Math.floor`

Comment: I use this website reference: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/

The problem is, some countries dont use 5+ but 6+, if I have 1.5, its stay 1.5, but 1.6 is 2.
https://jsfiddle.net/tevez15/ywm8bonp/2/

@RoryMcCrossan, my problem is if I have 18.235, can't be 18.24, but 18.236 can be

Comment: I add some code in the awnser... I hope this help to understand my question. Sorry.

Comment: Well if you need to round with another pattern than internationally used, you need to implement this yourself:

    if(value - Math.floor(value) < 0.6) {
      return Math.floor(value)
    }
    else return Math.ceil(value)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ywm8bonp/14/ to see an example with decimal places taking in account.

Comment: @ImreNagy in your example you use 1.005, and return 1.01, but in that case, this will return 1.00, because just up value in 6. https://jsfiddle.net/tevez15/ywm8bonp/18/

Comment: Yes, but now, with the new url, I change the val and: https://jsfiddle.net/tevez15/ywm8bonp/21/

Comment: Sorry, you need to alter the if clause for the decimal places: https://jsfiddle.net/ywm8bonp/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is possible again to answer I'd like to formulate my solution in a proper way.

Your way to round numbers can be archieved by the following code:

```
var myRounding = function(value, decimalplaces) {
    var decFac = decimalFactor(decimalplaces);
    var facVal = value * decFac;
    if(facVal - Math.floor(facVal) < 0.6) { 
        return Math.floor(facVal) / decFac;
    } 
    return Math.ceil(facVal) / decFac;
}

var decimalFactor = function(decimalplaces) {
    if(!decimalplaces)
        decimalplaces = 0;
    return Math.pow(10,decimalplaces);
}
```